# Calling a Sub() On Joystick StateChanged XInput Method

Tags: vb.net

Recently i was working on a school project app written in vb.net.

I have a problem adding support for My Joystick With XInput Method.
I found a code on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492473/Using-XInput-to-access-an-Xbox-Controller-in-M?

but it has a little bug i think : when Joystick.StateChanged Event Raises I call a Sub on My MainWindow Class But it Says : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

```
Public WithEvents XJoy As XboxController = Nothing
Public ReadOnly Property XInputJoy As XboxController
    Get
        Return XJoy
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub JoystickStateChanged(sender As Object, e As XboxControllerStateChangedEventArgs) Handles XJoy.StateChanged
    If XJoy.IsXPressed Then
        VV1()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub VV1()
    TEST1_Text.Text = "X Pressed"
End Sub

Public Sub WindowLoaded()

    XJoy = XboxController.RetrieveController(0)
    XboxController.StartPolling()
    If XJoy.IsConnected Then
        MessageBox.Show("Found Joystick In XInput Mode !")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note That Xinput is Based On Polling And We must use a polling Loop that is running on another thread. but how can i create connection between that thread and my mainwindow (Call a Sub) ???

Thanks Very Much , And Sorry for my Bad English

Im Using Visual Studio 2012 , And My Joystick Is XBox Like (XInput Supported.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using WPF, in which case you need to set the .Text property on the UI thread. You can do this using [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824(v=vs.110).aspx), i.e.

```
Public Sub VV1()
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() TEST1_Text.Text = "X Pressed")
End Sub
```

or call the VV1 function via the Dispatcher:

```
Public Sub JoystickStateChanged(sender As Object, e As XboxControllerStateChangedEventArgs) Handles XJoy.StateChanged
    If XJoy.IsXPressed Then
       Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(VV1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Frist Method _ BeginInvoke(Sub() ... ) Works But Second one BeginInvoke(VV1) does not. also i Fixed the problem by using a DispatcherTimer to do the looping code Instead of Using another thread.(Is It OK ??)

Comment: Happy to hear you've got it working :) DispatcherTimer is a good approach too